# Looking for an example of a bounded set.

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Consider the local base over the space of complex continuous functions over $[0,1]$ (denoted by $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$) defined for each fixed $x\in [0,1]$ and $\epsilon>0$ by

$$\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon,x} = \{f\in \mathcal{C}[0,1] : |f(x)| < \epsilon\}.$$

In an effort to better understand what is going on with the topology induced by this local base, I am interested in finding examples of a sets which is not simply equivalence classes of the zero function on $[0,1]$ or constant functions that is bounded in a topological sense (assuming such a set even exists).

---

My observations:

The definition of topological boundedness is really confusing me. That is, a set $S$ is bounded with respect to a topology $\tau$ if there is a $s$ such that

$$S\subseteq t\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon,x}$$

whenever $t>s$ for every open neighborhood of the origin.

Since this must be true for every single fixed $\epsilon$ and $x$, in particular as $\epsilon$ gets small and $x$ varies, the only function that would live inside all of the $\mathcal{B}$'s should be the zero function I think. Even if I were to consider only a single $\epsilon$ and $x$, the existence of a singular  $t$ associated with this $\mathcal{B}$ that scales some collection of each elements $f\in \mathcal{B}$ into $S$ seems very strong if $|S|>1$.

Because each element of the local base only cares about the function value at a single point, it seems like each local base would look very different and scaling by $t$'s is unlikely to get set containment. When I consider such a set $S$ that must have this property for **every** neighborhood, it seems like such an incredibly strong condition that I can't fathom what they are.

Comment: What you have there isn’t a local base at any point of $\mathscr{C}[0,1]$. If you allow all finite intersections of sets of the form $\mathscr{B}_{\epsilon,x}$, you get a local base at the zero function in the topology of pointwise convergence.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I was under the impression under  "Definition via seminorms" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_convex_topological_vector_space#Definition_via_seminorms that the set in the wikipedia entry, $U_{B,\epsilon}(y)$,  coincides with my $\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon,x}$. Pages 27-29 of Rudin's functional analysis, does say that this set need not be a local base so I must be misunderstanding the wikipedia entry.

Comment: No, your $\mathscr{B}_{\epsilon,x}=U_{\{x\},\epsilon}(\mathbf{0})$, where $\mathbf{0}$ is the zero function. What you want is $\mathscr{B}_{\epsilon,F}(g)$ for finite $F\subseteq[0,1]$ and $g\in\mathscr{C}[0,1]$, defined as $$\{f\in\mathscr{C}[0,1]:|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon\text{ for each }x\in F\}\;.$$

Comment: If you want to generate the entire topology, you need a local base at each point of $\mathscr{C}[0,1]$. In this case it turns out that you can get this by taking a local base at $\mathbf{0}$ and looking at all of its translates. In the notation of my last comment, for instance, $\mathscr{B}_{\epsilon,F}(g)=g+\mathscr{B}_{\epsilon,F}(\mathbf{0})$. \\ Yes, in your notation $\mathscr{B}_{\epsilon/2,x}\subseteq\mathscr{B}_{\epsilon,x}$, but these sets don’t give you a base at $\mathbf{0}$, because there are nbhds of $\mathbf{0}$ that don’t contain any of them. For instance, the set ...

Comment: ... of $f$ such that $|f(0)|<\frac12$ **and** $|f(1)|<\frac12$ does not contain any of your sets. You need finite intersections of your sets; that’s why the Wikipedia article has a parameter $F$ that is a finite subset of $[0,1]$ instead of just a single point.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I deleted my comment because I kept convincing myself I was right and then convincing myself I was wrong again. Those comments were very enlightening and I will have to think about it for much longer and revisit my question afterwards. Thank you very much

Comment: You’re very welcome.